# Reprodução de bugs intermitentes

Tags: código-fonte

Estou com um problema para resolver na empresa e gostaria de uma orientação a respeito. Qual o procedimento correto para localizar um erro que aconteceu apenas uma vez?

Por exemplo, no meu caso o cliente foi lançar um movimento no sistema, e algo aconteceu que um grande volume de informações foram excluídas das tabelas correlacionadas no procedimento.

Contudo, com a base de dados do cliente em mãos, refazendo o passo a passo não dá mais o erro, existe alguma técnica para administrar esse tipo de situação?

Comment: +1, boa pergunta. Problemas assim as vezes acontecem aqui na empresa também

Comment: Editei o título para deixá-lo mais claro e alinhado com o objetivo da pergunta. Agora, tenho minhas dúvidas se a tag [tag:código-fonte] é a mais adequada. Deixei a tag por não conseguir pensar em uma melhor.

Comment: É uma situação complicada. Provavelmente a resposta é fazer o que já fez. Sem uma situação concreta não sei se dá para ajudar mais que isso. Na verdade o problema pode ter a ver com o ambiente. O que eu sempre falo que a maioria dos programadores acham que um código está bom se ele testa e está funcionando. Mas funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Quando faz errado acontece esse tipo de coisa, alguém rodou o código em uma situação diferente do que foi testado e aí enrosca. Tem caso que é virtualmente impossível reproduzir mesmo. Eu acho esta pergunta ampla demais.

Comment: Ok. @bigown vc tem razão, é amplo o assunto, concordo com você. 
Inclusive meu questionamento se deu por isso mesmo, existem muitas coisas que ainda não domino na programação, entrei na POO agora e pensei que poderia existir alguma sequência de ações coordenadas pra esse caso.

Comment: Não tem nada geral a não ser tentar reproduzir todas condições. Existem algumas técnicas bem avançadas em tecnologias específicas, coisas em que o código foi preparado para isso. A ideia é que agora o leite já está derramado. Quando a aplicação é feita pensando nisso, dá para evitar muita situação assim e se ocorrer dá para ter bastante informação de como e porque ocorreu. Prevenir é melhor que remediar.

Comment: Ta certo, a respeito do problema, vou proseguir tentando simular e ver onde consigo chegar. Obrigado pelas respostas. Agora em relação as técnicas que vc mensionou, poderia citar alguns exemplos ou alguma referência para aprimorar neste questito?